# Wordpress multiple slugs as classes

Tags: wordpress

It has to be simple, but I'm stuck right now..

I use

```
<?php foreach( get_the_category() as $cat ) { echo $cat->slug . ''; } ?>
```

to display slugs as classes, but when there are 2 categories assigned, 2 slugs are echoed but as a single word.

for example Category slugs: Single & Buff ,
generate as SingleBuff.

How can they be separated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try it

```
<?php 
$cat_slug = array();
foreach( get_the_category() as $cat ) 
{ 
$cat_slug[] = $cat->slug; 
} 
?>
```

now echo as:

```
<?php echo $cat_slug[0]; ?>
<?php echo $cat_slug[1]; ?>
<?php echo $cat_slug[2]; ?>
.
.
.
.
. and so on
```